# What kind of stochastic processes can Ljung–Box_test apply to or assume?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

[Ljung-Box test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) tests zero autocorrelation in a time series. I wonder what type of stochastic processes the test assumes on the time series? For example, whenever autocorrelation exists?

By assumption, I mean the one that holds under both the null and alternative hypotheses. So the null will be the assumption plus zero autocorrelation. (Therefore the alternative will be the assumption plus nonzero autocorrelation.) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The null hypothesis for the Ljung–Box test is that the residuals from a stationary ARMA($p$,$q$) process are independent & identically distributed normal deviates—Gaussian white noise. The test statistic over $m$ lags then has an asymptotically $\chi2_{m-p-q}$ distribution. Carrying out the test on the mean-centred ranks of the residuals is a straightforward way to increase its robustness.

Ljung & Box (1978), "On a measure of lack of fit in time series models", *Biometrika*, **65**, 2.

[Burns (2002), "Robustness of the Ljung-Box Test and its Rank Equivalent", *SSRN*.](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=443560)

Comment: thanks. (1) so what is the alternative? (e.g. does the alternative assume  a stationary ARMA(p,q) process, possibly with identically distributed residuals?) (2) And the assumption that is true to both the null and alternative, i.e. the union of the null and alternative? (e.g. does both null and alternative assume  a stationary ARMA(p,q) process, possibly with identically distributed residuals?)

Comment: The alternative's that the null ain't. I don't know that the L-B test was designed for maximum power against any specific alternative; the ones of interest are those where there *is* auto-correlation. The 2nd paper cited illustrates power analysis for AR(1) alternatives with a variety of white noise distributions.